# Show content whose "team" field matches the user "team" field

Tags: 7, views

The users on my site all have a field named "team" and my content types also have the same field.

I want to create a views page that shows all nodes where that "team" field equals the same field on the user node.

Example:

**USERS:**

```
user1, team: team1
user2, team: team1
user3, team: team2
```

**NODES:**

```
node1, team: team2
node2, team: team1
node3, team: team1
```

When I'm logged in as user 3, I want my view to show node 1.

I know that I have to work with the contextual filters and context but I'm unable to get the output I need.

Comment: Both the OG Groups module, and the Group module can do this.

Comment: what type is the team field? is that taxonomy term?

Comment: Sorry, yes, it's a taxonomy term.

Comment: @Jaypan both these modules can be a solution but what I need is so simple that I would prefer to not install modules for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to set this up is through the **Content: Has taxonomy term ID** Contextual filter.

1. In Content Views listing your nodes add that Contextual filter and set it up:
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **Taxonomy term ID from URL**
   **Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy blocks**
   **Filter to items that share any term**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **Taxonomy term**
   **[your vocabulary]**
   **Term ID**
   Adjust the other option as necessary.

   Now if you enter some taxonomy term ID into the Views Preview field, it will be picked up by the Contextual filter and show only nodes that have been tagged with that term.
2. Create a block Display and place your block in a region shown on entities that have the taxonomy term ID chosen. The block will show all nodes that share the term.

In your case if you place that block on User Profile pages, it will show the nodes related through the same Taxonomy term.

---

If you want to show that Block anywhere on the site, and have it take the Context of the currently logged in user you have to approach it a bit differently.

There may be more ways on how to achieve this, here's one:

1. In the original Views where you show a list of nodes add a Relationship for the Taxonomy term field (**Field: Team**).
2. Then add another Relationship that is reverse, going from Taxonomy term to the field on Users (**Taxonomy term: User using …**). This is where the term matching is done, the second Relationship will use the first one. This introduces the User info into your content Views.
3. Then add the Contextual filter for User ID (**User Uid**), it will use the second Relationship. Set up the Contextual to use the logged in user context:
   `When the filter value is NOT available`
   **Provide default value**
   **User ID from logged in user**
   `When the filter value IS available or a default is provided`
   **Specify validation criteria**
   **User ID**
   **Single ID**
4. Place the Block anywhere on the site and it will only show nodes related to the user that is currently logged in, even if you place it on user profiles and view other users profiles!

Comment: Thanks prkos. Tried the second part of your answer but I get 0 results. From what I understand the view is of type content, not user right?

Comment: Yes, it should be Content type View if you want to show/list nodes. The user is just the context for which nodes to show. It's impossible to figure out what might be wrong. Go step by step and test each change that it does what it should. Add User field using the second Relatinship to test that it matches correctly. Only then add the Contextual filter, you can test that Contextual in a new Test views without Relationships.

Comment: Solved. I think I was missing something and I don't know what.

Comment: Yes, sometimes IT problems just work the second time you try :) I'm glad it's working now :)